# Find sequence to a target number using restricted set of primitive operations

Tags: c++, c++17, dynamic-programming

> Given an integer , compute the minimum number of operations(+1, x2, x3) needed
> to obtain the number  starting from the number 1.

I did this using this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v(n+1, 0);
    v[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if((v[i + 1] == 0) || (v[i + 1] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[i + 1] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((2*i <= n) && (v[2*i] == 0 || v[2*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[2*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((3*i <= n) && (v[3*i] == 0 || v[3*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[3*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << v[n] - 1 << endl;
    vector<int> solution;
    while(n > 1)
    {
        solution.push_back(n);
        if(v[n - 1] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n-1;
        }
        else if(n%2 == 0 && v[n/2] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n/2;
        }
        else if(n%3 == 0 && v[n/3] == v[n] - 1)
        {
            n = n/3;
        }
    }
    solution.push_back(1);
    reverse(solution.begin(), solution.end());
    for(size_t k = 0; k < solution.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << solution[k] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Input:

```
5
```

Output:

```
3
1 2 4 5
```

Do you have any optimized way to do this?

Comment: The algorithm looks good already. What clue make you think it is possible to improve it ? Bad performance on a competitive site ?

Comment: @Damien yes exactly, the grader is not accepting it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `using namespace std;`

Stop doing this.  It is a easy, but sloppy, way to code; a change to the standard library that introduces a new identifier can break your code.

Being explicit, and writing `std::vector` instead of `vector` everywhere would be painful.  But there is a middle ground:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
```

Now you can lazily use `vector`, without fear that something you are not using from the standard library will suddenly become defined, colliding with your identifiers, and causing carnage.

## White space

Either put white space around all binary operators, like `v[i + 1]`, or never put the white space around the binary operators, like `v[i*2]`.  But be consistent.

## `cout << endl;`

Don't use this; it slows your code down.  The `endl` manipulator does two things: it adds `\n` to the stream **AND** it flushes the stream.  If you don't need to flush the stream (and you rarely do), simply write

```
cout << '\n';
```

## Avoid repeated calls to functions that return the same result

```
for(int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++)
```

What is the value of `v.size()`?  Will it ever change?  Can the compiler tell it won't, and optimize it out?  Could you store the value in a local variable to avoid the repeated function calls?

Or ... you could use the variable that already exists: `n`.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

## Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY)

```
        if((v[i + 1] == 0) || (v[i + 1] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[i + 1] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((2*i <= n) && (v[2*i] == 0 || v[2*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[2*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
        if((3*i <= n) && (v[3*i] == 0 || v[3*i] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[3*i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
```

These statements look very similar.

```
        if((target <= n) && (v[target] == 0 || v[target] > v[i] + 1))
        {
            v[target] = v[i] + 1;
        }
```

You could pull them out into a function:

```
inline void explore_step(vector<int> &v, int n, int i, int target) {
    if ((target <= n) && (v[target] == 0 || v[target] > v[i] + 1)) {
        v[target] = v[i] + 1;
    }
}
```

And then write:

```
        explore_step(v, n, i, i+1);
        explore_step(v, n, i, i*2);
        explore_step(v, n, i, i*3);
```

## Optimization

You approach takes \$O(n)\$ time, because you explore each value from `1` to `n`.

You do this, because you don't know which values are going to be useful in reaching the target value, and test things like `v[2*i] > v[i] + 1` because you don't know which values could be reached via a faster path.

A slightly better approach:

- seed `1` into a list of values to explore
- for each value in the list of values to explore:

  - for each of the 3 target values `i+1`, `i*2`, & `i*3` if `<= n`:

    - if `v[target] == 0`, then

      - store `v[target] = i`
      - add `target` to the list of values to explore
      - if `target == n`, stop

Consider `n = 10`.

```
explore = [1], value = 1, targets = [2, -, 3]
explore = [1, 2, 3], value = 2, targets = [-, 4, 6]
explore = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], value = 3, targets = [-, -, 9]
explore = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9], value = 4, targets = [5, 8, -]
explore = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 5, 8], value = 6, targets = [7, -, -]
explore = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 5, 8, 7], value = 9, targets = [10, -, -]
```

You could use a `queue` for `explore`, but a `vector` of length `n`, and just walking forward through the items works fine.

Notice that all values reachable after 1 step `[2, 3]` are processed before values reachable after 2 steps [4, 6, 9], and would be processed before those values reachable after 3 steps [5, 8, 7], and so on.

More over, we've built up a trail of breadcrumbs for the fastest path.

```
v[10] = 9
v[9] = 3
v[3] = 1
```

So no searching is required to find the correct path.

Implementation left to student.

---

Can we do better?  What if we started with `n`, and explored `n-1`, `n/2`, and `n/3`?  An odd value can't lead to an `n/2` point, and a non-multiple-of-3 can't lead to a `n/3` point, so you may be pruning more values out of the search, so might be slightly faster.

```
[28] -> [27, 14]
     -> [26, 9, 13, 7]
     -> [25, 13, 8, 3, 12, 6]
     -> [24, 12, 4, 2, 1!, ....]
```